# NSMutableArray and NSDictionary Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have one NSMutableArray called SubList that contains 262 element. Every object is a NSDictionary!

This code works like a charm!

```
for (NSDictionary *element in listSub){
    [cell.textLabel setText:[element objectForKey:@"title"]];  

}
```

But if I try to use use this code I get a SIGBART error!

```
NSDictionary * element = [listSub objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

[cell.textLabel setText:[element objectForKey:@"title"]];
```

So what's the problem?

*EDit the problem is at this line

```
NSDictionary * element = [listSub objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

and this is the description
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89a8d90'
Thanks

**Edit 
This is the output of listSub!

```
listSub: {(
        {
        categories =         (
                        {
                id = "user/14761688561595773457/label/Web Programming";
                label = "Web Programming";
            }
        );
        firstitemmsec = 1265885595862;
        id = "feed/http://feeds.feedburner.com/FamousBloggers";
        sortid = A11327DE;
        title = "Famous Bloggers";
    },
        {
        categories =         (
                        {
                id = "user/14761688561595773457/label/Hacking";
                label = Hacking;
            }
        );
        firstitemmsec = 1241258413829;
        htmlUrl = "http://backtrack-italia.blogspot.com/";
        id = "feed/http://feeds2.feedburner.com/BackTrackItalia";
        sortid = E8A04F76;
        title = "Back Track Italia";
    },
        {
        categories =         (
                        {
                id = "user/14761688561595773457/label/Hacking";
                label = Hacking;
            }
        );
        firstitemmsec = 1245376992188;
        htmlUrl = "http://www.offensive-security.com";
        id = "feed/http://www.offensive-security.com/blog/feed/";
        sortid = 92F57555;
        title = "BackTrack Information Security Distribution";
    },
        {
        categories =         (
                        {
                id = "user/14761688561595773457/label/iOS Developer";
                label = "iOS Developer";
            }
        );
        firstitemmsec = 1296830392306;
        htmlUrl = "http://amix.dk/Main/";
        id = "feed/http://feeds.feedburner.com/amixdk";
        sortid = 110C52C3;
        title = "amix.dk blog";
    },
        {
        categories =         (
                        {
                id = "user/14761688561595773457/label/Apple News";
                label = "Apple News";
            }
        );
        firstitemmsec = 1285261350202;
        htmlUrl = "http://www.appletvhacks.net";
        id = "feed/http://www.appletvhacks.net/feed/";
        sortid = 81125D2E;
        title = "Apple TV Hacks";
    },
        {
        categories =         (
                        {
                id = "user/14761688561595773457/label/Apple News";
                label = "Apple News";
            }
        );
        firstitemmsec = 1293230300220;
        htmlUrl = "http://www.appletvitalia.it";
        id = "feed/http://www.appletvitalia.it/feed/";
        sortid = 892FE61C;
        title = "Apple Tv Italia";
    },
        {
        categories =         (
                        {
                id = "user/14761688561595773457/label/Apple News";
                label = "Apple News";
            }
        );
        firstitemmsec = 1270115980935;
        htmlUrl = "http://www.appleecious.com";
        id = "feed/http://feeds2.feedburner.com/appleecious";
        sortid = 00B5AFC2;
        title = Appleecious;
    },
        {
        categories =         (
                        {
                id = "user/14761688561595773457/label/Hacking";
                label = Hacking;
            }
        );
        firstitemmsec = 1258495136927;
        htmlUrl = "http://www.rawseo.com/news";
        id = "feed/http://www.rawseo.com/news/feed/";
        sortid = D6766911;
        title = "A blend of programming and seo";
    },
        {
        categories =         (
                        {
                id = "user/14761688561595773457/label/Seo e Web Marketing";
                label = "Seo e Web Marketing";
            }
        );
        firstitemmsec = 1233684720758;
        htmlUrl = "http://it-adsense.blogspot.com/";
        id = "feed/http://it-adsense.blogspot.com/atom.xml";
        sortid = 9FB570ED;
        title = "AdSense Blog-Italiano";
    },
        {
        categories =         (
        );
        firstitemmsec = 1277627346000;
        htmlUrl = "http://aext.net";
        id = "feed/http://feeds.feedburner.com/aextnet";
        sortid = 70800CFE;
        title = "AEXT.NET NET MAGAZINE";
    },
        {
        categories =         (
        );
        firstitemmsec = 1217001547735;
        htmlUrl = "http://www.alessandroscoscia.it";
        id = "feed/http://feeds.feedburner.com/alessandroscoscia";
        sortid = 51CB8E6E;
        title = "Alessandro Scoscia";
    },
        {
        categories =         (
                        {
                id = "user/14761688561595773457/label/iOS Developer";
                label = "iOS Developer";
            }
        );
...
```

I'm sure that it isn't a NSSet.

Now I post the code that I'm using to populate my array.

```
 NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData  *dataReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataReply encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"testing %@",string);


    SBJsonParser *vol= [[SBJsonParser alloc]init];
    if (string) {
        NSArray *feeds = [vol objectWithString:string error:nil];
        NSDictionary *results = [string JSONValue];
        NSArray *subs = [results valueForKey:@"subscriptions"];

        for (NSDictionary *iscrizione in subs){

            [subscriptions addObject:iscrizione];

        }
```

This is part of another class and also in this part of my code if i try to do something like this:
NSDictionary * element = [listSub objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog([element objectForKey:@"title"]);

I get the same error while if I try a loop like this

```
for (NSDictionary *element in listSub){
    [cell.textLabel setText:[element objectForKey:@"title"]];  

}
```

Everythings works fine without NSSet errors. This make me crazy!

Comment: Can you paste the error message also...

Comment: what is lol, you are calling [lol objectForKey:@"title"] and get right result,While having dictonary in element?

Comment: Have you any `%` in `[element objectForKey:@"title"]`?

Comment: check updated one.call [listSub retain] where you access data on it.

Comment: I added  [listSub retain]  before the NSDictionary * element = [listSub objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; but doesn't work :(

Comment: Show us the line where you create and populate the listSub object.

Comment: I repeat: Do `NSLog(@"listSub = %@", [listSub description]);` right after you set listSub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that `listSub` was not properly retained and therefore released already. The memory is now re-used and the object at that address is now an `__NSCFSet`, which does not respond to `objectAtIndex:`.

Note that autoreleased objects returned by a convenience class method like `[NSMutableArray arrayWithXXX]` should be retained and only released when not needed anymore. The best way to be sure they are retained is to declare a `@property(retain) NSArray *subList`, `@synthesize` it and use `self.subList` in all cases except perhaps in `dealloc`.

### Addition

It was suggested that the method that created `subList` returned a set and not an array. If that were the case, the simple loop at the begining of the answer would not function either. That is why I find it very unlikely that `subList` was originally an `NSSet`, and much more likely that the array was overreleased and dealloced and the memory re-used for the `NSSet`.

### **Please do what people who want to help you ask of you**.

Add the line

```
NSLog(@"listSub: %@", listSub);
```

at the place where listSub is set and also right before the error line. Then look in the error log what it displays and tell us.

Comment: Or it might be that whatever method he used to get listSub actually does return a set.

Comment: How can I see if the method return a set?

Comment: Maybe look at the source for the method?  Or do `NSLog(@"listSub = %@", [listSub description]);` after it's set?

Comment: @JeremyP: But then the simple loop at the beginning of the question should not work either. That is what made me think it was already dealloced. This is not regular code returning a set instead of an array, AFAICS.

Comment: See my comment above -- the `for(... in ...)` construct works on any "collection".

Comment: Yes, I know it works on any collection, but it won't return the items he put in the array, right?

Comment: It may return the items he put in the set.  He apparently doesn't know what goes on inside the method that provided the value for listSub.

Comment: The contain exsists! I've upadated my post! take a look please!

Comment: thank you! I've found solution for my problem! I've allocated another new local array called subscriptions so the real subscriptions array that I use in the rest of code was empty!

Comment: @paul_1991: How do you expect someone here to find this, unless we're psychic? But even for an empty array, you can't get an error about `__NSCFSet` and using `objectAtIndex:`on an empty array should give a totally different error too. I suspect you never initialized the local subList and that is why it contained the value of a pointer to an object that was there, on the stack, before. You still didn't do what people actually asked, i.e. show where subList was allocated (you showed how it was filled, not how it was allocated) and what the NSLog() calls some asked you to put in actually said.

Comment: @paul_1991: continued... **Next time you ask people for help, please do what people ask you to do**, i.e. post the code people ask for (you still didn't) and the results of `NSLog()` calls, etc. Some of us spent our valuable spare time to help you, so I think it is nothing but fair that you provide what people ask, in order to assist them helping you. This was more or less a complete waste of our time. **We would probably have spotted the error in a few minutes if you had given more information, i.e. more code**. Please don't waste your and other people's time that way again.

Comment: + 1000 => I had a similar problem and the answer for me was to use self.subList instead of subList !

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
[cell.textLabel setText:[element objectForKey:@"title"]];
```

What is that "lol"??

Comment: Sorry I make I mistake with cut and paste... I edit my code. the error is at this line NSDictionary * element = [listSub objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

Answer (score 1):

`listSub` isn't an array, it's an `NSSet`.

Comment: Either the interface that produced `listSub` returned an `NSSet`, or (probably a little less likely) as Rudy suggested `listSub` was not properly retained and the `NSSet` has been created in the storage formerly occupied by an `NSArray`.  What that, in turn, means is that it's time for you to roll up your sleeves and do some actual debugging, rather than asking for a canned solution.

Comment: @Daniel: if a method "by accident" returned a set instead of an array, the simple loop at the beginning of his question would fail too. There, subList is apparently a valid array. So that array must have been lost and been replaced by a set. I doubt he'd do that in his code, so I think my scenario is still the most likely.

Comment: Nope, the loop is good with a set.  "element in NSSet" works as well as "element in NSArray".  An NSSet is essentially an unordered NSArray (and, lacking order, `objectAtIndex` is meaningless).

Comment: The loop is fine, but not the results.

Comment: What's wrong with the results?  (The OP hasn't shown us the results, BTW.)

Comment: @Daniel: Well, it turned out it was an uninitialized local variable with the same name as his global or ivar subList. If he had posted the entire routine, I'm sure someone would have spotted that within a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

problem is here

```
[cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:[element objectForKey:@"title"]]];
```

when you are call stringWithFormat then you need to give format in string literal form like this

```
[cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[element objectForKey:@"title"]]];
```

or direct set the text with out calling `stringWithFormat:`

your array got released some where, so for solving the problem you need to call retain on tyour array at right place.

Comment: Although a correct explanation, the **real** answer is that he doesn't need to use `stringWithFormat:` when he already has a string.

Comment: Yes I edit my code, the error isn't at that line! take a look!

Comment: @Abizern Ya but in case if he is having any object which is not NSString class object and calling stringWithFormat without declaring format then this kind of situation occurs.so may be here the object is not NSString.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one.

```
NSDictionary * element = [listSub objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
[cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[element objectForKey:@"title"]]];
```

Or try this as you have edit your question,  **Edit**

```
NSDictionary *element = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[listSub objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[cell.textLabel setText:[element objectForKey:@"title"]];
[element release];
```

Comment: Get the same error again. *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ea8f30'

Comment: It's telling you that the `objectAtIndex` selector is being used on an NSSet, not an NSArray.